how to run a PS cmd in synapse python notebook such that the exe is in data lake container and pass it path to file in same data lake as input param?
How to run a PowerShell command in synapse python notebook such that the executable is in a data lake container and pass it a path to a file in same data lake as input parameter?
I have already tried the following:
import subprocess

# data defined earlier:
# storage acc: samplesa
# container: samplecontainersa
# storage_path = "abfss://samplecontainersa@samplesa.dfs.core.windows.net/"
# file_system_name = "folder1/testexe.exe"
# file_path = storage_path + "folder1/testexe.exe"
# testtxt = "folder1/testtxt.txt"
# testtxt_path = storage_path + "folder1/testtxt.txt"

# Read the contents of the .exe file
exe_client = blob_service_client.get_blob_client(container=container_name, blob=file_system_name)
downloaded_exe = exe_client.download_blob().readall()
testtxt_client = blob_service_client.get_blob_client(container=container_name, blob=testtxt)
testtxt_txt = testtxt_client.download_blob().readall()
# params = " -SubmissionId " + submissions_path + " -Password malware -Output " + storage_path + "folder1"
powershell_command = f"{downloaded_exe} -testtxtId  {testtxt_path} -Password malware -Output {storage_path}folder1"

# Execute the .exe file
try:
    # subprocess.run([downloaded_exe], shell=True)
    # subprocess.run(f"{downloaded_exe} {params}", shell=True)
    subprocess.call(f"{powershell_command}", shell=True)
except Exception as e:
    print(f"Error executing the .exe file: {e}")

but I keep getting this error:
/bin/sh: -c: line 1: syntax error near unexpected token `('

thanks!
